# When was the option "Needs improvement" added to the flag dialog?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, flags

It's the first time I see this option:

[image]

When was this option added? And do you have any opinion on whether we should prefer this as a "flag" rather than VTC with "Needs detail or clarity"?

I'm a bit confused about this.

Comment: I just realized that actually clicking on this takes you directly to the VTC dialog. So guess there's no difference. Still not sure I understand why though..

Comment: users who don't have the 3k privilege to cast close and reopen votes will *flag* posts for closure using this route.

Comment: Hmm ok. But has this always been the case, or has it then been "reintroduced" to users with over 3K? Because it seems redundant for all 3K+ users. 

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think there has been a change - people like you and I who have 3k plus tend only to flag questions as spam, so rarely glance down at the other flag options :)

Comment: @Zanna I'm pretty sure this option has not always been present in the Flag dialog box until recently. I'm rather observant about things like this. But anyhow, it doesn't matter that much anyway, hehe. 

Comment: I suppose a benefit of this option for users with 3k plus is that if one changes one's mind about flagging the post and decides to vote to close it instead one may click on through. For users who have only just earned the close/reopen privilege, especially those who have been active in flagging to close, it may be a useful guide. The new description also reminds us why posts should be closed and that they can be reopened (I guess that's the idea anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option used to be named "should be closed"*. [It was changed to "needs improvement"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396754) in April 2020, going by the date of the linked post.

It leads to the various close options. Users who don't have close and reopen vote privilege may cast flags to close on the question, which puts it into the close votes review queue.

<sub>* I don't know when or how the option of flagging to close came into being. It must have been in the very ancient past.</sub>